# MySQL: Outputting the product count 7 days ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm completely stumped on this one.

Lets say I have a product count as depicted

[image]

How do I output the user count from 7 days ago?

*Sample output* should be like this:

[image]

I thought of doing this with `MINUS` keyword, but then this is not working.

Comment: seven days ago from which date? from current date?

Comment: nopes from the latest date .Please see output.

Comment: Please explain your expected output.

Comment: @1000111 the sample output is available in the question

Comment: Lets say I have only 11 days of data, I need the latest date product count, latest - 7 days ago product count.

Comment: Okay I got it @user4943236. Please check the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for this query:

```
SELECT 
t.Date AS dateid,
t.Product_Count,
P.Product_Count AS product_count_7dago
FROM producttable P

INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   Date,
   Date - INTERVAL 7 DAY sevenDaysBefore,
  Product_Count
  FROM producttable) t
ON t.sevenDaysBefore = P.Date;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45cf9e/1/0)

**Explanation:**

- First I created a result set where each date has corresponding **seven
  days before date**.
- Then I made an `inner join` between this result set and original table
  `ON` the **seven days before date** field.
- After performing the `INNER JOIN` those entries which don't have
  corresponding **seven days before date** in the table will be dropped.
- Now you are left with only those dates which have corresponding **seven
  days before date**.

Comment: Amazing. I was thinking on that lines only but couldn't figure out. thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A.Date AS dateid,
A.Product_Count,
B.Product_Count AS product_count_7dago
FROM producttable AS A
INNER JOIN producttable B
ON A.Date - INTERVAL 7 DAY = B.Date
```

You can join the table again and make the join condition is equal to before 7 days.